# OpsCenter Security superuser has default setting failure

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I'm running into a bit of issue when trying to get the best practice rule "Security superuser has default setting" to pass.

I've followed DataStax documentation (https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/sec/secChangingDefaultSuperuser.html) about how to change the default superuser.

After changing the default super user password (cassandra/cassandra) the best practise fails and gives me:

```
Problem when checking login on 'ip address':
Please update the password for the user 'cassandra'.
```

Looking at the logs they show bad credentials, which is most likely because OpsCenter is still using cassandra default password (cassandra).

```
2016-07-08 13:43:00+0000 [cluster_name]  INFO: Starting scheduled job 20921ac5-c5a3-488b-b01e-a90e5189182d

2016-07-08 13:43:00+0000 []  INFO: Starting factory <cassandra.io.twistedreactor.TwistedConnectionClientFactory instance at 0x3ecd878>

2016-07-08 13:43:00+0000 []  INFO: Stopping factory <cassandra.io.twistedreactor.TwistedConnectionClientFactory instance at 0x3ecd878>

2016-07-08 13:43:00+0000 []  WARN: [control connection] Error connecting to 256.256.256.256: Failed to authenticate to
256.256.256.256: code=0100 [Bad credentials] message="Username and/or password are incorrect"

2016-07-08 13:43:00+0000 [] ERROR: Control connection failed to connect, shutting down Cluster: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'256.256.256.256': AuthenticationFailed(u'Failed to authenticate to
256.256.256.256: code=0100 [Bad credentials] message="Username and/or password are incorrect"',)})

2016-07-08 13:43:00+0000 [] ERROR: Problem when checking login on
256.256.256.256: Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/bestpractice/BestPracticeRules.py", line 227, in check_cassandra_user
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.7/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1018, in _inlineCallbacks
            result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.7/shared/amd64/twisted/python/failure.py", line 349, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
            return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/CassandraService.py", line 136, in check_connection
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.7/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1018, in _inlineCallbacks
            result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.7/shared/amd64/twisted/python/failure.py", line 349, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
            return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WrappedDriver.py", line 163, in connect
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.7/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1018, in _inlineCallbacks
            result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.7/shared/amd64/twisted/python/failure.py", line 349, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
            return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WrappedDriver.py", line 310, in _hacky_connect
        NoHostAvailable: Unable to connect to any seed nodes, tried ['256.256.256.256']

2016-07-08 13:43:00+0000 [cluster_name] ERROR: The best practice rule 'Security superuser has default setting' has failed.
```

My address.yaml file looks following:

```
stomp_interface: 256.256.256.255
cassandra_user: cassandra
cassandra_pass: ********** (correct cassandra password)
```

And my cluster.conf looks following

```
[jmx]
username =
password =
port = 7199

[destinations]
active =

[agents]
backup_staging_dir = /path/to/commitlog/backup

[cassandra]
username = cassandra
seed_hosts = 256.256.256.253, 256.256.256.254
password = ******** (correct password)
cql_port = 9042
```

Using OpsCenter 5.2.4 and DataStax Enterprise 4.8.8.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The opscenterd process will connect directly to your cluster for a number of operations. Since changing the password, you'll need to edit the cluster configuration to update the password.

Here are the steps for changing the setting through the UI:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/opsc/online_help/opscModifyingClusterSetting_t.html

Or you can directly edit the cluster conf file:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/opsc/configure/opscConnectionConfig_r.html#opscConnectionConfig__cassandra-password

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I have, at least, the correct username and password in the cluster.conf file. Maybe there is something else missing, I added the cluster.conf file the the question.

Comment: Did you restart OpsCenter after updating the password in the cluster conf file? OpsCenter doesn't watch the conf file and will only read the configuration on startup.

Comment: Yes I did restart OpsCenter only, then tried again restarting both OpsCenter and the DataStax agent and both of which did not work.

Comment: The problem you're running into was a bug discovered in v5.2.4 and logged as OPSC-7281 (Best practice rule for "Security superuser has default setting" not working) in our internal database. It has since been fixed in OpsCenter 6.0. (https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.0/opsc/release_notes/opscReleaseNotes600.html?scroll=opscReleaseNotes600__BPS). Unfortunately there is no work around to the issue.